# Mandatory PIN entry for certificate signing for each ComputeSignature call

Tags: c#, .net, x509certificate

I'm signing data with a certificate originally located inside a USB token device. The code is working but there is one problem: after the first signature, the user is no longer prompted to enter the PIN. Only if the user unplugs the USB device and plug it again, the PIN is required again.

```
SignedXml signedXml  = new SignedXml();
//...
signedXml.ComputeSignature(); //Here is when the user is asked to enter the PIN
```

I need to ensure that every time `ComputeSignature()` is called, the user is asked to enter his PIN. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is controlled by the device driver software of the module. Most software of this kind has a setting regarding if the PIN can be cached. There's no uniform interface to control this setting.

Interesting though, - most developers have an exactly opposite problem of being prompted each time.