# X509Certificate2 request PIN

Tags: c#, x509certificate, x509, x509certificate2

I am able to successfully identify client certificates in a .NET thick client app, and the user is able to successfully select one.

```
X509Store store = new X509Store("MY", StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
var fcollection = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByApplicationPolicy, "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2", true);
// other stuff where user selects one of them
```

Now how do I ask the user to answer the challenge (e.g. PIN in this case)?

I [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15258676/mandatory-pin-entry-for-certificate-signing-for-each-computesignature-call) there's a SignedXML.ComputeSignature() class, but it takes a byte stream, and I'm not sure where that comes from (perhaps in certificate.RawData[]?).

I'm not really as interested in getting the actual pin as I am that the card/pin match.

**EDIT:**

I tried using the private key from the smart card (and even encrypted from it), but I don't get asked for my PIN.

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsacsp = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)certificate.PrivateKey;
UnicodeEncoding ByteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();
byte[] dataToEncrypt = ByteConverter.GetBytes("Data to Encrypt");
var encryptedData = RSAEncrypt(dataToEncrypt, rsacsp.ExportParameters(false), false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the PIN request happens when I call RSACryptoServiceProvidersa.Decrypt.

Here's example code that worked perfectly for me in a Console app:

http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2010/02/encryptingdecrypting-using.html

Much simpler in ASP.NET (aside from all the IIS config hassles/mysteries ...).

Answer (score 0):

If this is a smartcard, the pin prompt will happen when you try to use the private key of the certificate.

You need to use the certificate somehow, and validate the result. For example, you might use the certificate to sign something. Once that signature operation happens, the pin prompt will appear.

If you don't really need to "use" the certificate, just want to validate that it's there and the user knows the pin, then you need some sort of proof of work. The certificate could be used to sign a challenge, and a remote server could validate the signature uses a key that belongs to a trusted root. Keep in mind this is difficult to get right, such as making sure you aren't open to a replay attack, etc.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I added the code posted above in the edit where the private key is used to encrypt some arbitrary text, but I don't get asked for the PIN.

Comment: It doesn't sound like the private key / certificate is pin protected then, if it really did encrypt / sign something.

Comment: perhaps not ... when I do this from MVC when SslFlags="SslNegotationCertificate" it solicits for my PIN and it won't work unless it is the right PIN. So it seems like this should also be do-able from a thick client app.